# Rename tag: [pomelo] → [pomelo-game-server] or [pomelo-nodejs]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [pomelo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pomelo) tag (nodejs game server) does mostly get (mis-)used as a synonym for the [pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql) tag (MySQL database provider for EF Core).

Many recent questions have already been updated, so that they use the correct tag. But there remain about 20 questions that still use the wrong tag.

I therefore suggest to rename the [pomelo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pomelo) tag to `pomelo-game-server` or `pomelo-nodejs`, to make it clearly distinguishable from [pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql).

I am happy to retag the remaining 20 questions, once the rename/merge has been approved and done. Alternatively, I can also copy all the question links or IDs here, if necessary.

---

After that, it might also make sense to make [pomelo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pomelo) a synonym for [pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql).

While there is only very minor maintenance development going on for the game server repo (and only *very* occasional questions about the project here on SO), the EF Core provider repo is in active development, has millions of downloads and frequent questions about the project here on SO.